# Get Primary Key and Foreign Key constraint

Tags: java, ms-access

Get Primary Key and Foreign Key constraint from MS Access Database in java Program.

I tried to use `desc table_name` but it didn't work.

I have even tried `DatabaseMetaData.getMetaData(null,null,"table_name")` but it didn't work either.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please give us more details? In what way doesn't it work?

Comment: i want to get constraints of a table specificly primary key and foreign key of a MS Access database table using java code

Like i have tried it for mysql its simply "DESC TABLENAME" but in MS ACCESS it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this will bring problems working with MS Access Database, but reading the JDBC specification
You should do the following steps.

For getting table from DB use

```
DatabaseMetaData meta = connection.getMetaData();
ResultSet tablesRs = meta.getTables(null, null, "table_name", new String[]{"TABLE"});
```

For getting primary keys use

```
meta.getPrimaryKeys(null, null, "table_name");
```

For getting Foreign keys use

```
meta.getExportedKeys(null, null, "table_name");
```

**EDIT:**
It seems that it wasn't implemented for ODBC Driver, 
You have to look this post how to get primary keys with ODBC driver working with MS Access Database.
[here](http://www.roseindia.net/answers/viewqa/JDBC/12952-Suns-JDBC-ODBC-driver-does-not-implement-the-getPrimaryKeys%28%29-method-for-the-DatabaseMetaData-Objects..html)
is used `meta.getIndexInfo(...)` to get primary keys

Comment: when i am trying to use meta.getPrimaryKeys(null, null, "table_name");


I am getting an error java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver does not support this function

Comment: It seems that getPrimaryKeys() wasn't implemented for ODBC driver. I have edited the post

Comment: getIndexInfo gets me whether there is primary key present in my table but it does not help me to get which metadata has primary key value
and also i am not able to get foreign key

Answer (score 0):

use `DatabaseMetadata` class.

From that class use `getPrimaryKeys()` method

Comment: rs= md.getPrimaryKeys(null, null, "Chromo");


ResultSetMetaData rd1=rs1.getMetaData();


      for(int i=0;i<rd1.getColumnCount();i++)
      {
            System.out.println("here "+rd1.getColumnName(i+1));
                          
            System.out.println("here "+rd1.getPrecision(i+1));
      }


I have tried this but ever I am not able to get Data and getting a error java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver does not support this function

Answer (score 0):

The retrieval of the meta data for a table is easy. You construct an `SQL` on your table and execute it. From the resulting `ResultSet` you can retrieve the `MetaDataResultSet` which contains among other stuff the field name, the field type, `nullable and autoincrement`:
Just try this:

```
 ResultSet set =stmt.executeQuery(sql);//stmt is your Prepared or Callable Statement object
    ResultSetMetaData resultMeta = set.getMetaData();
     for (int i=1;i< =resultMeta.getColumnCount();i++)
     {
      String fieldName = resultMeta.getColumnName(i);
       int type = resultMeta.getColumnType(i); // java.sql.Types
       Class _fieldType = convertType(type);
       boolean nullable = resultMeta.isNullable(i)!=java.sql.ResultSetMetaData.columnNoNulls;
       boolean isAutoincrement = resultMeta.isAutoIncrement(i);
        System.out.printf("Field: %s, %s, nullable %b, autoincrement
       %b%n",fieldName,_fieldType.getName(),nullable,isAutoincrement);
     }
```

The type is specified as an integer constant in java.sql.Types.
Information on the constraints can be retrieved from the DatabaseMetaData which can bee retrieved from the connection. There are 3 methods:

`getPrimaryKeys(catalog,schema,table):` to retrieve a ResultSet that contains; one entry for each column for each primary key.

`getIndexInfo(catalog,schema,table,unique,false):` to retrieve indices unique and otherwise. You retrieve a ResultSet that contains one entry for each column for each index. If unique is false the result contains unique and non unique keys.

`getExportedKeys(catalog,schema,table):` to retrieve a ResultSet that contains all foreign keys; one entry for each column for each key.

Comment: I have tried to use this drivers for connectivity with access 


Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver").newInstance();


String url = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ="+dbPath;

But I am getting an error java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver does not support this function

after using
   
rs = md.getPrimaryKeys(null, "GeneProducts", tablename);

Comment: Metadata interface implementation was implemented by driver vendors. It may not be supported by some driver and some db. Here is text from javadoc: Some DatabaseMetaData methods return lists of information in the form of ResultSet objects. Regular ResultSet methods, such as getString and getInt, can be used to retrieve the data from these ResultSet objects. If a given form of metadata is not available, an empty ResultSet will be returned.

Comment: Just try it:

DatabaseMetaData dm = conn.getMetaData( );
ResultSet rs = dm.getExportedKeys( "" , "" , "table1" );
while( rs.next( ) ) 
{    
  String pkey = rs.getString("PKCOLUMN_NAME");
  System.out.println("primary key = " + pkey);
}

Comment: I have already mentioned I am getting an error 
I have tried to use this drivers for connectivity with access Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver").newInstance(); String url = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ="+dbPath; But I am getting an error java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver does not support this function after using rs = md.getExportedKeys(null, "GeneProducts", tablename)

or should i change driver name

Comment: I am surprised that why you are using type 1 driver driver? You should try type 4 driver. Type 1 is an old story. So i suggest you to change your driver to type 4.
Have a look
http://www.hxtt.com/access.html

Comment: i have download required jar but now what should i use for class.forName();  and what should be the url to pass to DriverManager

Comment: Just have a look here, I hope it will help you

http://www.hxtt.com/support/access1145007915.html

Answer (score 0):

//For getting the Column name of primary key

```
      DatabaseMetaData meta=conn.getMetaData();
      rs= meta.getTables(null, null, tablename, new String[]{"TABLE"});
      rs=meta.getPrimaryKeys(null, null, tablename);
      while(rs.next())
          System.out.println("Primery Key :"+rs.getString(4));
```

//and also foreign key constraint

```
      rs=meta.getExportedKeys(null, null, tablename);
      while(rs.next())
          System.out.println("Foreign Key :"+rs.getString(4));
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:

```
 public String getPrimaryKey(String table) throws SQLException
  { 
    con = null;
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=//access_file_path/database_name.mdb", "username", "password");   
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM "+table);
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
    int cols = rsmd.getColumnCount(); 
    String primaryKey_columnName = "";
    boolean isAutoIncrement;

    for(int x = 1;x<=cols;x++){
        isAutoIncrement = rsmd.isAutoIncrement(x);
        if(isAutoIncrement){
           primaryKey_columnName = rsmd.getColumnName(x);
          }
      } 
     rs.close();
     con.close();

     return primaryKey_columnName;    
  }
```